# Django ChoiceField not working insed {% for sub in subs %}

Tags: python, django, choicefield

Inside my django project i have a template called formquestions.html. Inside the template I am looping through all sub categories from my database (right now it is only 1 for testing purposes). My issue is that my `ChoiceField` is not dropping down so you may select other options. If I move outside of the for loop it works just fine.

```
# form.py
DATA_DISPLAY_TYPE = (
    ('input', 'Input'),
    ('select', 'Select'),
    ('checkbox', 'CheckBox'),
)    
class EditSubInfo(forms.Form):
    help_text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    data_display_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DATA_DISPLAY_TYPE)


# formquestions.html
{% for sub in subs %}
    Name: sub.name
    Choices: {{form.data_display_type}}
{% endfor %}
```

The `ChoiceField` renders just fine. But when you try to click on it, nothing happens. If I move it outside of the for loop, it will work just fine. Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: I think form fields are like generators in python, they can be used only once. I'm not sure. check it once.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I've used pure html as well with select tags. It renders just fine but won't click while inside the for loop.